# Como hacer efectos de anclaje sutiles de navegación con la rueda del mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap

Hola estoy queriendo hacer un sitio parecido a este ejemplo http://ambient.elated-themes.com/vertical-slider-showcase/ lo que quiero hacer con javascript / jquery es una especie de anclado que cuando giro la rueda del mouse baje a cada seccion que detallo en el nav. el codigo que arme fue este:

```
<nav id="mainnav" class="">
    <ul class="dotnav dotnav-vertical dotnav-right nav">
        <li><a href="#home"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#about"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#skills"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#projects"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#novedades"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact-2"></a></li>         
    </ul>
</nav>
```

con cada seccion

```
<div id="home"></div>
```

la rutina de javascript que arme es esta

```
          $('.awesome-tooltip').tooltip({
          placement: 'left'
      });  
      $('body').scrollspy({ 
          target: '#mainnav', 
          offset: 002
      });  

      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
          if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
              var target = $(this.hash);
              target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              if (target.length) {                   
                  $('html, body').animate({
                      scrollTop: target.offset().top
                  }, 500);
                  return false;
              }
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

mira el plugin "One Page Scroll"

[Create an Apple-like one page scroller website (iPhone 5S website) with One Page Scroll plugin](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll)

y un [ejemplo del propio sitio](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html)

Comment: gracias por el dato!

Answer (score 0):

Una forma con jQuery sería crear los eventos para **detectar y ejecutar el scroll del mouse**. A partir de allí **disparas** los demás eventos para ir recorriendo los **bullets** (según la página de demostración que pusiste) e ir **marcando el bullet activo**. Luego **disparas** otro evento para mostrar la **sección correspondiente al bullet activo**.

```js
var 
$document = $(document),
$sections = $('section'),
$bullets = $('#Bullets > li'),
$activeBullet = $bullets.first();

/** EVENTOS DEL MOUSE */

$document.on('mousewheel', function(e){
 
    if( e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0 ) $document.trigger('scrollDown');
  
    else $document.trigger('scrollUp');
  
})
.on('scrollDown', function(){
  
    var $next = $activeBullet.next();
  
    $activeBullet = !!$next.length ? $next : $bullets.first();
  
    $activeBullet.trigger('active');
  
})
.on('scrollUp', function(){

    var $prev = $activeBullet.prev();
  
    $activeBullet = !!$prev.length ? $prev : $bullets.last();
  
    $activeBullet.trigger('active');

});

/** EVENTOS DE LOS BULLETS */

$bullets.on('active', function(e){

    $bullets.removeClass('active');
  
    var $li = $(this).addClass('active');  
  
    $sections.filter('#' + $li.attr('data-section')).trigger('active');

})
.on('click', function(){
 
    $(this).trigger('active');
  
});

/** EVENTOS DE LAS SECCIONES */
$sections.on('active', function(){
 
    $sections.removeClass('active');
  
    var $section = $(this).addClass('active');  

    /* Alguna acción más */

});

$activeBullet.trigger('active');
```

```css
section {
  
  position: fixed;
  top:0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: -9999;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  
}

section.active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: -9998;
}

li.active {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="uno" style="background-color: red;"></section>
<section id="dos"style="background-color: blue;"></section>
<section id="tres" style="background-color: green;"></section>
<section id="cuatro" style="background-color: orange;"></section>

<ul id="Bullets">
  <li data-section="uno"></li>
  <li data-section="dos"></li>
  <li data-section="tres"></li>
  <li data-section="cuatro"></li>
</ul>
```

A partir de allí puedes generar las acciones que quieras para tu **sección activa**. Yo en este caso puse todas las secciones en posición fija cubriendo todo el espacio de la pantalla y las voy mostrando mediante una transición de CSS si tienen la clase **active**.

Comment: Gracias Dario por el ejemplo me vino muy bien lo voy a probar.